# Expected identifier or '(' objective C

Tags: objective-c

Just starting out with Objective C so please be gentle. I've got a class as follows:

Card.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Card : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger x;
-(NSUInteger) getNum;
@end
```

Card.m

```
#import "Card.h"

@implementation Card
-(NSUInteger) getNum {
    return self.x;
}    
@end
```

main.c

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include "Card.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile, I get a load of errors, first one is:

NSObjCRuntime.h: Parse Issue: Expected identifier or '('.

I know this is something stupid - just hoping somebody here can spot what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: It's common convention in Objective-C to *not* prefix getters with "get" and instead simply name them the property being fetched. Also, it's convention to spell out the full name. In your case `getNum` would be written as `number`.

Comment: Thanks @David for the pointers. I guess convention is important. In this case I was purely creating a test method, but I take your points on board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you actually compiling this with an Objective C compiler? The traditional extension to instruct GCC and clang to use ObjC is `.m` (not `.c`).

Comment: I just created an OSX 'command line tool' in Xcode and it created main.c for me. It actually imported CoreFoundation (which I changed in testing). I created the class Deck using the new file menu. I'm building it in XCode too.

Comment: It looks like you might have created a C project, rather than Objective C. When I create a test application, I get "Main.m", an Objective C file. The compiler is complaining because Foundation.h is an Objective C header, but you're using it in a pure C file (main.c).

Comment: That makes sense! Strange that Xcode allows a 'command line tool' with no ability to import objective c classes ... unless there is a way?

Comment: You can configure it to create one. With XCode 5, make sure the "Type" of the command line project is set to "Foundation". Or, you can alter the project after it's (but it's more fiddly).

Comment: Thanks @Adam - that has answered my question.